# Place div with position absolute above not yet loaded elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a vertical list, for items with categories and subcategories.
Each item has a floating menu with its description, shown and hide when the mouse is placed over (position absolute).
Because of the way the page is made, not all the elements of the tree are loaded at the beginning, but the elements inside the categories are only loaded by ajax and displayed when the user expands the category. 
The problem is that the floating description overlaps the next elements, but I cant make it to display above. I have tried changing the z-index, but this doesn't seem to work when position: absolute.
I think the cause of the error is that newly loaded elements are automatically placed on the top of the position: absolute element. I need to change this.
I'm sorry but I can't provide a Fiddle for this, the code would be huge and it has Jquery and ajax processing. But maybe describing the problem you can understand the reason.
Thanks!

Here how the first element is working:
[image]
Here how the second element is already on the bottom:
[image]

Comment: We can understood the situation, but we can't help you since there are no code to see and to test. This kind of questions, unfortunately for you, are offtopic in stackoverflow. Try to read first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask || http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem** or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you tried to change the z-index of the item that should be on top? or both, because most likely you need to specify it for all elements, such as: `.top: { z-index: 102; } .bottom { z-index: 101; }`. If you have provided the sample code, i would look

Comment: Sorry, because of the Ajax part is impossible for me to upload it. Chaning z indexes don't make any change, I think because z-index don't apply when the element is positioned absolute...

Comment: no, z-index and `position: absolute` must work together